# Implemented claims based roles

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm recently started a new project using MVC and entity framework (All new to myself). In my application I have 2 types of users, admin and a non-admin.

I've seeded an admin into my database in the configuration.cs file under the seed method:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<Users>(context);
            var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);

            var admin1 = new Users
            {
                UserName = "admin@email.com"
            };

            userManager.Create(admin1, "password");
            AddUserAndRole(context, userManager, admin1);
```

AddUserAndRole method:

```
bool AddUserAndRole(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationUserManager um, Users user)
        {
            IdentityResult ir;
            var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>
                (new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

            ir = um.Create(new IdentityRole("canEdit"));
            ir = um.AddToRole(user.Id, "canEdit");
            return ir.Succeeded; 
        }
```

Once migrating and running the solution, I've checked the AspNetUserLogins table to ensure that the user's ID has been successfully associated with the new claims role, but for some reason it's not updating, but when I look inside the AspNetRoles table, the claim gets added to that alongside an ID which is not associated with the admin1 created.

Wondering if anybody could point out where I'm going wrong.

Thank you in advance for any help and please inform me if i've missed out any required information in this post. :)

Comment: What user does the claim get assigned to?

Comment: I've checked the AspNetUserClaims table and all is null, but I also checked the AspNetRoles table and it has created a 'canEdit' role and just give than an ID, I don't think its linked to a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @War is saying about roles and claims is very much true, however:

The table AspNetRoles contains two columns:

- Id: The id of the **Role** not the **User**
- Name: The name of the Role

Instead, you should look at the table AspNetUserRoles, which links User id's to Role id's (Columns UserID and RoleId)

But you also have another problem:

You are creating a new role every time you are trying to assign a user to, for example, "canEdit". That's why you are getting a new entry in AspNetRoles every time. There should only be one row per role name in that table.

So instead of using CreateRole every time, try something like

```
    bool AddUserAndRole(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationUserManager um, Users user)
    {
        IdentityResult ir;
        var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>
            (new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

        if(!rm.RoleExists("canEdit"))
        {
            var createResult = rm.Create(new IdentityRole("canEdit"));
            if(!createResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return um.AddToRole(user.Id, "canEdit").Succeeded;
    }
```

Or even better:

```
    bool AddUserAndRole(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationUserManager um, Users user, string roleName)
    {
        return AddUserToRole(context, um, user, "cadEdit");
    }
    bool AddUserToRole(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationUserManager um, Users user, string roleName)
    {
        IdentityResult ir;
        var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>
            (new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

        if(!rm.RoleExists(roleName))
        {
            var createResult = rm.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            if(!createResult.Succeeded)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return um.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName).Succeeded;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing your security concepts by the looks of things.

There are multiple things in play here typical "simplified" explanations of these are ...

> User  = Someone who can login
> Login = A set of credentials for a user
>
> Role  = Groups user and permissions together
> Claim = Something a claims provider says about a user

From the question it seems like you are mixing claims based auth and role based auth when you really seem only 2 simple roles (Users, and Admins)

Essentially pick either Claims based auth or Role based auth and use one or the other unless you really need the complexity, in such a case you have about 3 months minimum worth of reading and getting your head round all this stuff.

In short I would ...

Create the user, add the user to a role, then use role based auth until you need to go beyond that.

```
var adminUser = new Users
{
    UserName = "admin@email.com",
    Roles = new [] { "Admins", "Users" } 
};

userManager.Create(adminUser);
```